# Problems uploading picture into Firebase storage with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I Keep getting this alert when trying to upload a profpic:"FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'files/hhh.png'. (storage/unauthorized)"

ChatGpt recommended changing Firebase Storage rules to allow all users, authenticated or not, to access the file and read/write to it. Due to securuty reasons, I would rather not do that. Is there any way I can change my code to avoid doing this?

Here are my Firebase Security rules for Storage:

```
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is My firebase file:

```
    import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
   
  };

  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  export const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

  export {db, auth};
```

Here is my Login component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebase";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "./features/userSlice";
import hpic from "./images/screenshot.png";

import { storage } from './firebase';
import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

function Login() {
  
  const [progresspercent, setProgresspercent] = useState(0);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [profpic, setProfpic] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  

  const loginToApp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.target[1]?.files[0]

    if (!file) return;

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

    uploadTask.on("state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        setProgresspercent(progress);
      },
      (error) => {
        alert(error);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          setProfpic(downloadURL)
        });
      }
    );

    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userAuth) => {
        dispatch(
          login({
            email: userAuth.user.email,
            uid: userAuth.user.uid,
            displayName: userAuth.user.displayName,
            photoUrl: userAuth.user.photoURL,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  };

  const register = () => {
    if (!name) {
      return alert("Please enter your name!");
    }
  
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${profpic.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, profpic);
  
    uploadTask.on("state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        setProgresspercent(progress);
      },
      (error) => {
        alert(error);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
          auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((userAuth) => {
              userAuth.user
                .updateProfile({
                  displayName: name,
                  photoUrl: downloadURL,
                })
                .then(() => {
                  dispatch(
                    login({
                      email: userAuth.user.email,
                      uid: userAuth.user.uid,
                      displayName: name,
                      photoUrl: downloadURL,
                    })
                  );
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error));
        });
      }
    );
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1  bg-cover bg-center bg-fixed bg-opacity-80 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-100 to-green-100 md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 mx-auto py-20 px-6 md:px-32 items-center">
      <form className="flex flex-col items-center w-full">
        

        <input
          className="w-[60%]  h-12 px-3 rounded mb-3"
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Full name (required if registering)"
        />
        <input
          className="w-[60%] h-12 px-3 rounded mb-3 "
          type="file"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setProfpic(event.target.files[0]);
          }}
          placeholder="Optional Profile Pic (Paste URL Here)"
        />
        
        <input
          className="w-[60%]  h-12 px-3 rounded mb-3  "
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <input
          className="w-[60%]  h-12 px-3 rounded mb-3  "
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button
          className="w-[60%]  h-12 bg-green-500 rounded text-white font-bold mb-3 hover:bg-green-500 transition-all duration-200 hover:shadow-xl"
          type="submit"
          onClick={loginToApp}
        >
          Sign In
        </button>
        <p className="bg-white rounded p-2 text-center transition-all duration-200">
          Not a member? Fill out the information above and Click:
          <span
            className="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-900 pl-2 font-bold cursor-pointer"
            onClick={register}
          >
            Register Now
          </span>
        </p>
      </form>
      <div className="hidden md:block">
        <img
          className="w-full h-auto rounded-lg  border-2 border-gray-400 object-cover"
          src={hpic}
          alt="login pic"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Rather then describing what you want to avoid, can you describe what you want to implement. Who should be able to write files where? Also note that the most common scenarios are quite well covered in Firebase's documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics

Comment: I would just like to have a user register and when they register the profile picture  they enter in the input uploads to the storage. That way when they log in again the profile picture will render. I have not stated the portion of code which will pull the picture from the database yet but I am just trying to focus on this first.

Comment: So did you see the section of the docs I linked on [content-owner only access to files in Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#cloud-storage_2)?

Comment: Yes, still same alert with 403 Forbidden

Comment: Please edit your question to show your firebase storage security rules, because it seems like unauthenticated users cannot upload to firebase storage.